# Failed to parse altool output: Failed to parse PList data type

Tags: xamarin.forms, app-store, app-store-connect

It is happening when I attempt to deploy the application to the iOS app store. Before everything was ok. I tried to change App version and App code. I also updated VS Mac and XCode.

[image: Error window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I archived my app and tried to publish via Apple [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12). Then I got a normal error message.
After all I relogin in my Apple Developer Account + downloaded all profiles.